# cURL: Malformed encoding found in chunked-encoding, why?

Tags: ruby, apache, curl, cgi, chunked-encoding

I am experimenting with CGI and the chunked encoding ("Transfer-Encoding: chunked" HTTP header field.) This way files can be sent without a content-length header. I wrote a minimalistic CGI application in Ruby, to try it out. My code is the following (chunked.rb):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

puts "Date: Fri, 28 Nov 2015 09:59:59 GMT"
puts "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=\"ASCII-8BIT\""
puts "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg"
puts "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
puts

File.open("image.jpg","rb"){|f|
 while data=f.read(32)
   STDOUT.puts data.size.to_s(16)
   STDOUT.puts data
 end
 STDOUT.puts "0"
 STDOUT.puts
}
```

I took the idea and chunked format example from here: https://www.jmarshall.com/easy/http/

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

1a; ignore-stuff-here
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
10
1234567890abcdef
0
some-footer: some-value
another-footer: another-value
[blank line here]
```

As my CGI app resides in Apache cgi-bin directory, I can issue cURL:

```
curl  http://example.com/cgi-bin/chunked.rb -O -J
```

cURL should reassamble the original image.jpg file from the chunks, but unfortunately the saved file isn't complete, it is smaller than the original, and I get an error message too from cURL:

```
curl: (56) Malformed encoding found in chunked-encoding
```

However when I change line `data=f.read(32)` to something like `data=f.read(1024*50)`, then file is saved correctly. Using another, bigger file from the server make the CGI app useless again, I got the same error message again. What can I do to make my CGI app working, and to send the file correctly?

Comment: After the length and data, the separator should be a `CRLF` (\r\n).  `puts` just appends a `LF` (\n) so that may be the problem.  Does it work if you put `\r\n` after each length and data chunk?

Comment: In fact it should work "\r\n" and "\n" too. But problem solved, this is a Ruby "gotcha". Instead of "STDOUT.puts data"
I had to use "STDOUT.print data" followed by a "puts". This is because when data accidentally ends with a "\n" then ruby doesn't add an additional "\n". And sometimes this happens, when chunk size is interfere with "\n" bytes in the binary file.

Comment: Glad that set you on the right path - good job getting it working.

Answer (score 2):

So the working example:

```
    puts "Date: Fri, 28 Nov 2015 09:59:59 GMT"
    puts "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; charset=\"ASCII-8BIT\""
    puts "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=image.jpg"
    puts "Transfer-Encoding: chunked"
    puts

    File.open("image.jpg","rb"){|f|
     while data=f.read(32)
       STDOUT.puts data.size.to_s(16)
       STDOUT.print data
       STDOUT.puts
     end
     STDOUT.puts "0"
     STDOUT.puts
    }
```